# Dotnet run with launch-profile does not forward commandLineArgs

Tags: .net-core

I would like to start my project from the command line with `dotnet run --launch-profile XY`, where the launchSettings.json contains the right profile, and the profile XY has the `commandLineArgs` property. And it seems the launched program does not get these arguments. How can I fix it?